# How to enforce a single font on a generated HTML?

Tags: jquery, css, xslt

Our users are using a content editor tool that generates the simple web content for them.
From the editor they can select the font of the text and while I can't configure the editor to enforce them to use just one font I thought perhaps overriding this in the html generated as I have access to xsl and the css but this particular feature is not in the xsl but done by an outer framework.

So, when they select a font the editor generates something like:

```
<p class="my-class"><FONT face=georgia>Hello World</FONT></p>
```

I can't change the structure of the line above but I do have access to change my-class or plugin jquery code.
Using css (editing my-class"), jquery or xslt is there a way to replace any FONT face on the html with a different font of my choice?

Thanks!

Comment: If the editor really generates `<font>` tags, it's time to replace the editor.

Comment: I know but we can't any time soon, it's integrated in the SAP portal. Long story....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to remove the font tag:

1) Take a look at [unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

2) Or even for better performance, use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) :

```
$(".my-class").contents().replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });
```

Comment: This will remove the p, not the font tags, i think.

Comment: Agree with Virus721, any idea how to remove the font?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to get the contents first. I updated the code. Also, here is the JSFiddle I used to test http://jsfiddle.net/MR24V/

Comment: Yes yours actually does. Just checked the my generated code and it actually generates: <p><FONT face=georgia>Hello World</FONT></p>, anty idea how to tackle this?

Comment: Can I not simply replace all <font face* with empty string and do the same for </font>?

Comment: I think I solved it using: $("p").contents().replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });

Comment: or you can remove them targeting the font tag:
$('font[face="georgia"]').replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });

Comment: Ah even better! does it also supports wildcards so I can do this with any font?

Comment: Ah simply do $('font') :)

Answer (score 0):

Try : `font-family: "what you want" !important;`

Or

`$('font *').unwrap('font');`

Comment: Thanks. Where in the css shall I put it? Will !important work on all browsers?

Comment: !important can be overriden only by another !important so i guess anywhere in the CSS would probably work. Not sure it is supported in all browsers, but i think in most of them.

Comment: Just tried, doesn't seem to work. Gets overridden by font face

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple CSS, which works on all reasonably modern browsers, using an attribute selector:

```
FONT[face=georgia] { font-family: Arial, sans-serif }
```

In fact, if you wan everything to appear in your preferred font when possible, you can use simpler and even more widely supported CSS, using the universal selector `*`:

```
* { font-family: Arial, sans-serif }
```